# quasar get month in between using date

Tags: vue.js, quasar

```
const dateEnd = date.formatDate(timeStamp, ‘MMM YYYY’)

const dateStart = date.subtractFromDate(dateEnd, { month: 10 })
```

I have these two dates, I need a list of months between dateStart and dateEnd. May I know how can I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quasar framework has a number of utils that can help you. In this case, we will import the date utils from quasar like so.

```
import { date } from 'quasar';
```

The date util has functions for formatting, adding, subtracting dates, etc. I understand you have an end-date that you want to find a list of 11 months (end-date inclusive) from the start-date to the end-date.

```
let dateEnd = date.formatDate('2021/12/25', 'YYYY MMM D'); // e.g '2021/12/25'
let dateStart = date.subtractFromDate(dateEnd, { month: 10 });
```

You can achieve this by using a while loop, a counter at 0, and addToDate method of the date util.

```
let counter = 0;
let newDate = dateStart;
let monthsList = [];
while(counter <= 10){
  monthsList.push(date.formatDate(newDate, 'MMM'));
    newDate = date.addToDate(newDate, { month: 1 });
     counter++;
}
// output [ "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ]
```

Alternatively, you can use the array unshift method, a countdown from 10 and subtractFromDate method.

```
let counter = 10;
let newDate = dateEnd;
let monthsList = [];
while(counter >= 0){
  monthsList.unshift(date.formatDate(newDate, 'MMM'));
  newDate = date.subtractFromDate(newDate, { month: 1 });
  counter--;
}
```

You can read more about the date util in quasar here: https://quasar.dev/quasar-utils/date-utils

Answer (score 1):

You can use the library such as moment.js(https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-moment). You can use CDN as well for the same. It makes it easy to manipulate dates.

You can consider this snippet.

```
const dateStart = moment('2020-03-30');
const dateEnd = moment('2020-06-05');
let monthList = [];
while (dateEnd > dateStart || dateStart.format('M') === dateEnd.format('M')) {
   monthList.push(dateStart.format('MM'));
   dateStart.add(1,'month');
}
```

Here, you can push the month in the specific format. If you want to check date formats, you can [check here](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/01-format/)